difficult integral problem.. How do i approach this problem :$\int_0^1 (\sqrt[n]{(1-x^n)}-x)^2 \, dx$
Problem image
I have tried to solve this problem but none of the approaches have been successful. I think $n$ is any natural number and  tried to access it with beta function but failed. Can someone help me with the idea?
$$\int_0^1 (\sqrt[n]{\smash[b]{(1-x^n)}}-x)^2 \, dx$$

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Take $x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$

The parantheses in the root are not necessary.
